# Django Rest Framework return empty JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just start to implement Django Rest Framework by following several tutorials, however I can't fix my issue.

> Actually, my API return empty JSON string :

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

**This my code :**

from rest_framework import serializers
from wall.models import Articles

**serializer.py**

```
class ArticlesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Articles
        fields = ('title',)
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticlesView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Articles.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticlesSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
url('articles/', ArticlesView.as_view(), name="api-articles"),
```

**models.py**

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Titre")
```

I have many articles, so the JSON is returning as many article as I have in my database, but nothing else is displayed. Why ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should inherit your serializer from `serializers.ModelSerializer` not `serializers.Serializer`:

```
class ArticlesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Articles
        fields = ('title',)
```